# Java Comparator sorting order

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, comparable

I am using Java Comparator to sort one of my object based on some value in that object as below :

```
@Override
public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
   if(sortOrder.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCENDING))
       return compareTo(e2, e1);
   else
       return compareTo(e1, e2);
}

public int compareTo(Event e1, Event e2) {
     Tag t1 = getTag(e1, tagName, tagType); 
     Tag t2 = getTag(e2, tagName, tagType);

     if(t1!=null && t2!=null){
        if(t1.getRank()==null && t2.getRank()!=null)
            return 1;
        else if(t2.getRank()==null && t1.getRank()!=null)
            return -1;          
        else if (t1.getRank() < t2.getRank())
            return -1;
        else if (t1.getRank() > t2.getRank())
            return 1;
        else
            return e1.getId().compareTo(e2.getId()); //If rank null or equal compute rank based on id.
     }
     return 0;
}

Tag getTag(Event e, String tagName, TagTypeEnum tagType){
    List<Tag> tags = e.getTags();
    for(CTagsDO tag: tags){
        if((tag.getType().getId() == tagType.getId()) && (tag.getName().equals(tagName)))
            return tag;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here I am comparing 2 tags from 2 events which have some rank value. I sort my events based on this rank within the tag object.

The ASCENDING order works out well where it puts events with lowest rank values followed by events with higher ranks and puts all the events with null values of ranks at the end.

But for DESCENDING order, since I just do an inverted ASCENDING order, it puts all the events with null values of ranks at the top and then starts with the events with highest ranks and moves to the lowest ranks.

In DESCENDING sort, how do I get events with the highest ranks first and then the lower ranks and then the ones with the null value for ranks at the end?

Comment: Sort in only one order (say ASCENDING), then calling Collections.reverse() will change it to descending order. Don't re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: Might I suggest you use Guava to build your `Comparator`? Its ordering facilities are quite nice. https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/OrderingExplained It includes nifty `nullsFirst` and `nullsLast` methods.

Comment: @WhoAmI - that's exactly what OP said they DON'T want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `sortOrder.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCENDING)` in `compareTo` :

```
@Override
public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
   if(sortOrder.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCENDING))
       return compareTo(e2, e1);
   else
       return compareTo(e1, e2);
}

public int compareTo(Event e1, Event e2) {
     Tag t1 = getTag(e1, tagName, tagType); 
     Tag t2 = getTag(e2, tagName, tagType);

     if(t1!=null && t2!=null){
        if(t1.getRank()==null && t2.getRank()!=null)
            return sortOrder.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCENDING) ? 1 : -1;
        else if(t2.getRank()==null && t1.getRank()!=null)
            return sortOrder.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCENDING) ? -1 : 1;          
        else if (t1.getRank() < t2.getRank())
            return -1;
        else if (t1.getRank() > t2.getRank())
            return 1;
        else
            return e1.getId().compareTo(e2.getId()); //If rank null or equal compute rank based on id.
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would work except that the digits in the first 2 IF conditions should be swapped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do the null checks inside `compare`, before the logic that checks the `sortOrder`.  Then, only call `compareTo` once you know that both objects are not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the comparisons you're doing on them, I've assumed the `rank` and `id` fields are `Integer` objects. If that's the case, you can perform the null checks in a separate comparator and use that to order the objects based on the elements within the object.

I've simplified your scenario slightly by only working with the `Tag` class with `rank` and `id` elements.

So the abstracted null checking comparator would look like this: (I've included the ordering aspect in here too.)

```
public class NullsLastOrderedComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T>{

    public static final String ASCENDING = "ASCENDING";
    public static final String DESCENDING = "DESCENDING";

    private String sortOrder;

    public NullsLastOrderedComparator() {
        this(ASCENDING);
    }

    public NullsLastOrderedComparator(final String sortOrder) {
        this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
    }

    public int compare(final T o1, final T o2) {
        if( o1 == null && o2 == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        if( o1 == null ) {
            return 1;
        }

        if( o2 == null ) {
            return -1;
        }

        if(this.sortOrder.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCENDING)) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }

        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

This can then be used within a comparator for the class you want to order. You can include both of the elements you want to sort on by having a check for the initial result being 0 and ordering by the second element at that point. So here is an example `TagComparator` class:

```
public class TagComparator implements Comparator<Tag>{

    public static final String ASCENDING = "ASCENDING";
    public static final String DESCENDING = "DESCENDING";

    private String sortOrder;

    public TagComparator() {
        this(ASCENDING);
    }

    public TagComparator(final String sortOrder) {
        this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
    }

    public int compare(final Tag o1, final Tag o2) {
        final Comparator<Integer> comparator = new NullsLastOrderedComparator<Integer>(this.sortOrder);
        final int rankCompare = comparator.compare( o1.getRank(), o2.getRank() );

        if( rankCompare == 0 ) {
            return comparator.compare( o1.getId(), o2.getId() );
        }

        return compare;
    }
}
```

Then my tag class looks like this:

```
public class Tag {

    private Integer rank;
    private Integer id;

    public Tag(final Integer rank, final Integer id) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getRank() {
        return this.rank;
    }

    public void setRank(final Integer rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(final Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "R=" + this.rank + "&I=" + this.id; //Tag: " + super.toString() + "
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
        tags.add(new Tag(null, 1));
        tags.add(new Tag(1, 2));
        tags.add(new Tag(null, 2));
        tags.add(new Tag(6, 5));
        tags.add(new Tag(null, 4));
        tags.add(new Tag(6, 3));
        tags.add(new Tag(null, 3));
        tags.add(new Tag(3, 7));

        System.out.println("ASCENDING");
        Collections.sort(tags, new TagComparator(TagComparator.ASCENDING));
        System.out.println(tags);

        System.out.println("DESCENDING");
        Collections.sort(tags, new TagComparator(TagComparator.DESCENDING));
        System.out.println(tags);
    }
}
```

And the output is this:

> ASCENDING
>   [R=1&I=2, R=3&I=7, R=6&I=3, R=6&I=5, R=null&I=1, R=null&I=2, R=null&I=4, R=null&I=6]
>   DESCENDING
>   [R=6&I=5, R=6&I=3, R=3&I=7, R=1&I=2, R=null&I=6, R=null&I=4, R=null&I=2, R=null&I=1]

Comment: I like this approach but I also want to deal with events where the ranks have equal values, (null or either the same values). The reason I want to deal with it is because I am doing pagination after applying the sort and the database does not guarantee the order of the events returned everytime. So when I find equal values I sort the events based on their id.

Comment: Rightio, that's doable, I've edited my answer quite a bit. Reading the duplicate question flagged for this question and applying it to your scenario, I've used the null checking comparator and added in the ordering possibility there, then used it in the comparator for the Tag class and included both the rank and the id fields within that. You'll see in the output that the equal ranks are ordered by Id in the same ordering, but you could always change the ordering if you wanted. I also assumed id was an Integer, but it would work equally well with any object that implements Comparable.